# Chip or Fab position in center above content

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to achieve in React with Material-ui to display a chip or fab (floating action button) above the content when new post available on the bottom of the page.
Like below (instagram or google feed).

However I cannot center horizontally it:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
createStyles({
root: {
  position: 'fixed',
  bottom: theme.spacing(2),
  right: "auto",
  left: "auto",
  textAlign: "center",
  margin: "0 auto"
},}),);
...
const classes = useStyles();
return (
          <Chip className={classes.root}
            variant="outlined"
            avatar={<SyncIcon />}
            label="Clickable"
            onClick={handleClick}/>
);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: try to add `top: 0`

Comment: would like to add it on the bottom of the screen, but top:0 does not center it.

Comment: you want to center it horizontally ? It's already centered

Comment: It does not center horizontally, these images are just examples how I want to be shown.

Comment: Did you mean z-index?

Comment: It shows above other content, it just does not center horizontally the Chip.